# Isotope - display the name of the filter as a separate label

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm building a site using isotope with combination filters and would like to display the name of the selected filter next to the filtered items.

I've tried modifying the default code given in the metafizzy sample but am unable crack it:

```
<pre class="code-display"><code>$grid.isotope({...})</code></pre>
```

Any help appreciated...

Comment: How did you try, so that we can say if there's a simple way to do!

Comment: Please update the same in the question!

Comment: Ok - question updated :)

Comment: Show what code you are actually using. `$grid.isotope({...})` is not showing code you have tried.

Comment: I'm using unmodified isotope code. I was hoping someone who has done this before might be able to help...

Comment: Here's a link to a working sample http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ - instead of it showing '$grid.isotope({ filter: '.metal' })' I'd simply like it to display 'metal'